# Why do drivers for windows change for each release?

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card, printer, downgrade

from my experience it seems that comparability between windows versions is reasonably good, especially for the average home user, businesses not included.  why do the hardware manufacturers have to release drivers for each version of windows (XP, 7 , 8 etc) if the versions are supposed to be compatible between each other? this is very common with printers (canon PIXMA iP4000R for example) graphics cards, some peripherals etc.

It seems that this is very common both upgrading windows versions (xp to win7) or downgrading (win 8 to win7) in both cases (using clean install ) almost nothing works out of the box, and all the drivers have to be downloaded for that specific version of windows.

E.g. I downgraded a windows 8.1 laptop to windows 7- it took a few hours, since none of the windows 8 provided drivers would install, leaving me to go to each manufacturer and dig up drivers for windows 7. Similar case in upgrading versions. Is it not a waste of time to have to rewrite drivers all the time rather than create one driver that works across all versions, if they are supposed to be similar anyway (before windows 8 at least)

Comment: The only recent changes have been to the driver models.  This means that a driver can "crash" without taking the entire system with it.  Printers are one of the things that changed in Windows 8.  30-40% of the printers can use a generic driver going forward.  This wouldn't be possible if Microsoft never forced change, for example your display driver can now crash, without crashing the entire system.

Answer (score 1):

The reason most "normal" software works out of the box across windows versions is there is a layer beneath it that exposes a cross windows version/specific product compatible interface, that programs can talk to. That layer is the **Driver layer**.

Something has to exist that transforms the generic "work everywhere with every printer" interface any program written can talk to, to the "work with a Epsion 2230 Printer via USB using the windows 8.1 API interface".

Some API's don't change frequently and can be re-used (Printers in fact are a good example) and the file you download for Vista will be the same file you download for Windows 8.1. But some API's can change drastically and need OS version specific drivers.